# Deletion of multiple items in a collection bound to a datagridview takes forever

Tags: subsonic

This is not a question, cause I already answerd it. But it may be helpful to others, too.

Here's what happens:

1. Create a WinForm with a Datagridview and bind a Subsonic ...Collection with more then 500 objects loaded to it
2. Add some columns to the datagrid and make at least one autosizemode = fill
3. Add logic to delete all selected columns (i.e. on keypress -> delete)
4. Mark all records and delete them

This should take about 30 sec. on a high end pc (and scales up: 1 min for 1000 ...)

Cause:

Everytime you delete a row the collections ListChanged event is fired which causes the datagridview to recalculate the space needed for the autosized column (if someone is interested in the "internals" I attached a call graph.

Comment: btw - I assume you mean "= false" (lower case), and "= true" the second time.

Comment: If the second part is the answer, you should add it to the answers section and then mark it as the answer. Then people can upvote it as the answer, and you get reputation on SO for leaving a good answer (and maybe a badge for answering your own question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

While deleting, disable the ListChangedEvent:

```
mycollection.RaiseListChangedEvents = false;

// Delete multiple rows
foreach(DataGridViewRow row In dataGridView.SelectedRows) {
   dataGridView.Rows.Remove(row);
}


// After that you can re-enable the event:
mycollection.RaiseListChangedEvents = true;

// But you have to call
mycollection.ResetBindings();
//to let the datagridview perform at least one redraw.
```

The same task now takes only the blink of an eye

Comment: I fixed true/false typo and put the solution in the answer section
(thx to Marc Gravell and ranomore)